# Performance issue with elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to use elastic search for aggregated data: I have document in following format:

```
{
"userId" : "", 
"company": "foo" , 
"city"   : "fooCity",
"timeSpendonTask1InSec" : 5sec,
..............
"timeSpendonTask5InSec" : 10sec,
 "date" : "yyyy-mm-dd"
 }
```

I have near about 800k such items in a day. I am running elastic search query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId",
        "size": 25,
        "order": {
                "_count" : "desc" 
              }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_sec": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "timeSpendonTask1InSec"
          }
        },
        "sum_seconds" :{
            "sum" : {
            "field": "timeSpendonTask5InSec"
            }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have following shards settings:
I have separate index for each day.

```
2 Replica
number_of_shards 10
```

I am using AWS hosted ELS with following server settings:

```
    Instance count: 20
    Instance type: i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch
    Dedicated master instance count: 5
    Dedicated master instance type: i2.2xlarge.elasticsearch
    Enable zone awareness : true
```

I tried benchmarking ELS with different-2 aggregation bucket size from `5` to `100`. The ELS performance decreases as I increased bucket count.

But let's focus on bucket count 25. I am able to achieve only 100 RPS with above data, increasing further results in poor response time.
With 100 RPS the AWS monitoring dashboard shows cpu usages between 75% to 100%.

Any suggestion about what could be wrong in current setup? or Am I using ElasticSearch for wrong use case?

Comment: 10 shards and 2 replicas per day index with ~800K documents in each index sounds like too many shards. Consider reducing the number of shards to 1 with 1 replica, per day. How many daily indices do you need to store in ES?

Comment: @RussCam one index for each day, I need to return aggregation of last x hours data, where x is <= 24 hours.

Comment: how many days i.e. indices?

Comment: @RussCam 30 days, but most of time yesterday's index will only get touched. So yesterday data will be hot and other data will be just sitting there and getting only 1-2 request in a day.